# How to efficiently update more than one entity at a time on django-nonrel/app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

On django-nonrel on app engine, trying to use the "update" method on a QuerySet returns a NotImplementedError.  What is the most efficient way to do something like the following without using update?

```
goals = Goal.objects.filter(is_active=True).filter(deadline__lte=datetime.now())
goals.update(is_active=False, is_failed=True)
```

I could obviously loop through the goals, modifying and saving them one by one, but that seems extremely inefficient when there could potentially be a large number that needs changing.  Any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Batch puts are currently unsupported by django-norel - see http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#supported-and-unsupported-features

They *are* supported by the GAE SDK, however, like so:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
...
db.put(list_of_entities)
```

Keep in mind the restrictions in place for a datastore call, notably the 1 megabyte cap on data transfer.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable.  One thing I'm not clear on, though.  Currently I'm retrieving a django QuerySet.  In order to get this to work would I have to also retrieve the entities using the GAE SDK, or is there a simple way to turn the QuerySet into a list that can be used by db.put?  Or, I suppose, to turn a list of django-nonrel model instances into something that db.put would accept?

Comment: @Yual Does django-nonrel really return db.Model instances? That seems unlikely!

Comment: You're right. I was thinking App Engine Helper (http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/).

Comment: So, does this mean that I *would* have to fall back to using the GAE SDK to retrieve the entities, or is there another way to go about this using the django models?